# Rails pundit authorize specific controller actions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pundit

So I'm using Pundit to check for authorization access.

Before each controller in my application, I have

```
class ReservationsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authorize_reception!
```

With the helper module:

```
module AuthorizeMethods
  def authorize_admin!
    authorize User, :admin?
  end
  def authorize_reception!
    authorize user, :allow_reception?
  end
```

And also this User policy

```
class UserPolicy
  def initialize(user, _resource)
    @user = user
  end

  def admin?
    @user.hotel_admin
  end

  def reception?
    admin? || @user.allow_reception
  end
```

I now want to give access to reception roles to JUST the action :index from the reservations controller.

I came up with this:

```
class ReservationsController < ApplicationController
  sip_before_action :admin!, only: [:index]
  before_action :authorize_reception!, only: [:index]
```

So that for every other action it needs an admin, and for index, just a reception role. But my reception role, is having access to all actions of the controller (edit, delete, create), not just index.